# How to call multiple ID's in one function?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I've found this function that allows me to do what I want, but since I have many inputs, and I don't want to use this JS on all of them, I would like to call it only on couple of inputs. Can I do that by ID or something?

( I know that this sentence isn't one of the best, but I'm in a hurry, sorry)

```
var pastValue, pastSelectionStart, pastSelectionEnd;

$("input").on("keydown", function() {
    pastValue          = this.value;
    pastSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
    pastSelectionEnd   = this.selectionEnd;
}).on("input propertychange", function() {
    var regex = /^(100|(\d|[1-9]\d)(\.\d{0,2})?)$/;
                    
    if (this.value.length > 0 && !regex.test(this.value)) {
        this.value          = pastValue;
        this.selectionStart = pastSelectionStart;
        this.selectionEnd   = pastSelectionEnd;
    }
});
```

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, you can just stick the CSS selector in the `$()` - something like `$('#myFirstID, #mySecondID, #myThirdID')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post a jQuery alternative - since you've posted jQuery in your question code.

You just swap the CSS selector for an input element with the CSS selector for your specific element IDs, like so:

```
var pastValue, pastSelectionStart, pastSelectionEnd;

$("#myID1, #myID2, #myID3").on("keydown", function() {
    pastValue          = this.value;
    pastSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
    pastSelectionEnd   = this.selectionEnd;
}).on("input propertychange", function() {
    var regex = /^(100|(\d|[1-9]\d)(\.\d{0,2})?)$/;
                    
    if (this.value.length > 0 && !regex.test(this.value)) {
        this.value          = pastValue;
        this.selectionStart = pastSelectionStart;
        this.selectionEnd   = pastSelectionEnd;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually setting class on every input you want access would help, then accessing them using getElementsByClassName then you will add your event listener to all needed input.

```
const myInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("myInputs");
// consider myInputs as the class I gave to wanted inputs
myInputs.forEach(input=>{
input.addEventListener('click', functionHandler);
// functionHandler is the function where you will put your logic
})
```

Hope this is going to be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Give .inputTest class to all your inputs

```js
var inputs = $(".inputTest");
for (var obj of inputs) {
  var pastValue, pastSelectionStart, pastSelectionEnd;
  obj
    .on("keydown", function () {
      pastValue = this.value;
      pastSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
      pastSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
    })
    .on("input propertychange", function () {
      var regex = /^(100|(\d|[1-9]\d)(\.\d{0,2})?)$/;

      if (this.value.length > 0 && !regex.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = pastValue;
        this.selectionStart = pastSelectionStart;
        this.selectionEnd = pastSelectionEnd;
      }
    });
}
```